# How to create a password protected button in a vb.net form

Tags: vb.net, button

I have a `VB.NET` form that contains textboxes for the user to enter his details. I have a delete button in the same form that I want only the administrator or any authorized person to be able to use.

Basically, I want to make the `delete` button password protected so that the normal user can't delete any of his details. only the admin who has the admin password can delete it.

Is it possible to create a password protected button? I searched on the Internet but couldn't find any links that would help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a usability perspective I'd suggest a 'better' way to implement it would be to use some sort of role-based model, whereby the user authenticates when they begin using the app and role-specific form elements are then displayed accordingly.

If you really want a password to be entered to use a button, why not leave it enabled and in the click event handler, show a password-capture form? You only execute the rest of the code if the password is correct, else the event gets cancelled.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the quick response. That can indeed be another option. I just needed to know whether .NET provides a functionality to add a password to a button using any properties or do we have to manually as u suggested code it for our purpose?

Comment: No, there's no standard control that implements a 'password button' function, but you could always create a custom control yourself from other base classes - who knows, there may be a demand for such a control!

Answer (score 0):

My friend try this... CODE
`*Note:You should start the form with the delete button not enabled`

Let textbox1 contain password and button1 is the Delete button

```
Dim a=textbox1.text
Dim password="admin123"

If a=password Then
    button1.Enable=True
Else
    button2.enable=false
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dim as user as string
dim as pass as integer

user ="Admin"
pass ="1234"
if (user = username.text And pass =password.text) then
msgbox"GOOD"
ELSE
msgbox"SORRY"
end if
```

Comment: Elaborate your answer and add some explanation of what you did

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17503592)

Comment: @macmoonshine How does it not answer the question? Sure it is code-only and therefore not a good answer, but it does attempt to answer the question. Always be extra careful of reviews that say "This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content".